# Browser renders same css file differently

Tags: html, css

I am having issues when loading the css file from npm vs loading from a cdn.

Using the CDNs below, I'm able to render forms without any issues.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://unpkg.com/formiojs@latest/dist/formio.full.min.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/formiojs@3.9.3/dist/formio.full.min.css' />
```

But when I render the forms from a local CSS file, the form renders incorrectly

```
<link rel='stylesheet' src="/lib/formiojs/dist/formio.full.min.css" asp-append-version="true"/>
```

You can see the difference [here](https://files.catbox.moe/2v5u69.png)

Opening the 2 files in a browser and pasting into a diff tool, I noticed the difference seems to be around `'×'` which is located in 2 places.

When opening these 2 files in a text editor, they are identical.

In the browser, the CDN renders the string as `'×'` but the npm file renders as `'Ã—'`.

How can I get the CSS file to load with `'×'`?

I've tried adding `charset="UTF-8"` to the `link` element but it still doesn't render correctly.
I assume this has something to do with encoding.

The file in question can be found here
https://github.com/formio/formio.js/blob/master/dist/formio.full.css

Comment: Consider replacing `'×'` with `'\d7'` - the escape sequence for it. While this doesn't solve the encoding issue, it sort of side-steps it.

Comment: well, the 'x' renders correctly now, but the form still doesn't layout properly so i think the issue might lie elsewhere.

Comment: It looks like it might be an issue with JavaScript here, because it's specifically the "combo-box" fields that are displaying incorrectly. Any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors in console. I dont think its an issue with the js file because switching between local and cdn, the form stills renders correctly and no difference in a diff tool. The form breaks when changing the path for the css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That might be a typo but can you try replacing

`<link rel='stylesheet' src="/lib/formiojs/dist/formio.full.min.css" asp-append-version="true"/>`

with

`<link rel='stylesheet' href="/lib/formiojs/dist/formio.full.min.css" asp-append-version="true"/>`

The key difference being `href` is used instead of `src`.